# Why is this method group conversion ambiguous in C# 7.2 and lower?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0, c#-7.2, c#-7.1

Given the following class:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(int i, double d) {
        Integer = i;
        Double = d;
    }
    public int Integer {get;}
    public double Double {get;}

    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public static Foo CreateRandom() => new Foo(rand.Next(1,101), rand.NextDouble());
}
```

As well as this usage:

```
void Main()
{
    var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
                          .Select(_ => Foo.CreateRandom());

    Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(GetInteger)); // Fine
    Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(GetDouble)); // Ambiguous
    Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Double)); // Also fine
    Console.WriteLine(items.Sum((Func<Foo,double>)GetDouble)); // Cast required? Why?

    int GetInteger(Foo item) => item.Integer;
    double GetDouble(Foo item) => item.Double;
}
```

I am trying to figure out why it is that the `GetDouble` delegate conversion is considered ambiguous, and what exactly makes it different in this context from the labmda expression and the cast to the anonymous delegate.

Edit:
It looks like this does not affect C# 7.3, but does affect versions 7.2 and lower. Versions before local methods were added can be affected by making the GetInteger and GetDouble static.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to compile your code and it worked  without error message. Is there anything more in your test code?

Comment: @JonathonChase Your code doesn't reproduce the problem described.  The code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: C# Interactive shell says `(1,25): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int>)' and 'Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int?>)'` (edit: for `Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(GetDouble));`)

Comment: Latest LINQPad update no longer replicates, my current installs of Rider and VS 2017 do. Not sure why.

Comment: This glitch has been fixed in C# 7.3 Go to Build -> Advanced -> Language Version and change it to C# 7.3

Comment: hmmm, `Func<Foo, double> dd = (Foo x) => x.Double;` and then either `Enumerable.Sum(items, dd)`  or `items.Sum(dd)`, both of those work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's new in C# 7.3

> The following enhancements were made to existing features:
>
> - You can test == and != with tuple types.
> - You can use expression variables in more locations.
> - You may attach attributes to the backing field of auto-implemented    properties.
> - Method resolution when arguments differ by in has been improved.
> - *Overload resolution* now has fewer ambiguous cases.

The last fix was for this issue. Before that compiler had more difficulties resolving overloads.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3) to the source.